# iOS push notification not received when app suspended

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, push

My app receives push notifications when it is running in the foreground.  I have the following three methods implemented.

```
application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:
application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:
application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:
```

The app registers for the remote notifications successfully, and I send this token to my server.  When the app is running the foreground, I can see the push notification perfectly fine.

If the app is running and the user presses the home button, meaning the app is now suspended, the push notifications aren't triggering anything.  Nothing happens on the home screen.  No message, sound, or badge.

I've tried searching to see if someone has the same issue, but other peoples' issues deal more with capturing the notification in the correct appdelegate method after it has been received.

Any clues?

Comment: have you checked in settings if your app is allowed to receive notifications?

Comment: Did you end up figuring this problem out? I have the same exact problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390868/apple-push-notification-in-background-issue/19390972?noredirect=1#19390972