# APNS notification not waking app in background

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have an app that registers itself to be woken up in the background when an APNS notification is received (i.e., the `remote-notification` setting for `UIBackgroundModes`). In the vast majority of cases this works fine. An APNS notification comes in, the app is woken up and a call to my app delegate's `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` is made.

In some cases the APNS is received by the user but the app never gets woken up. It seems to only happen when the device has been inactive for a while (overnight, left behind for a weekend, etc). Once the user launches the app then everything is back to normal and subsequent APNS notifications again trigger the background wake-up.

Does anybody have an idea about what could trigger this?

Comment: APNs are not always 100%. It could be the network, carrier, etc... Others have had similar issues just like this. Take a look at this previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897575/apns-apple-push-notification-service-reliability

Comment: No, in my case the APNS notification is delivered successfully, but my app is not woken up in the background as it should.

Comment: This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390868/apple-push-notification-in-background-issue

Comment: @mcsheffrey, have you found some way to awake the IOS app (killed or closed state) via Push?