# Detect If push notifications were received when app is not launched and user didn't open the app through them

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

Is it possible to detect if a push notification was received while the app was offline (not in background or foreground ? given the case that the user open the app directly from the spring board and not from the push notification alert.

Comment: you can open your app by tapping on notification ..its already in build

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know Push Notification delivery status](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25830597/how-to-know-push-notification-delivery-status)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `AppDelegate` do this (sorry for swift implementation):

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // We see if we have a recent push notification date stored in the user defaults.
    // If there hasn't been a recent one sent this if block will not be entered.
    if let mostRecentPushNotificationDate = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("mostRecentPushNotification") as? NSDate {

        // We find the difference between when the notification was sent and when the app was opened
        let interval = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(mostRecentPushNotificationDate)

        // Check to see if we opened from the push notification
        if let notification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? [String: AnyObject] {
            print("we opened from the push notifcation and the time difference was \(interval) seconds.")
        }

        // We did not open from a push notification
        else {
            print("we opened from the spring board and the time difference was \(interval) seconds.")
        }

        // We remove the object from the store so if they open the app without a notification being sent we don't check this if block
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("mostRecentPushNotification")
    }


    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    // Set a flag when a push notification was sent
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(NSDate(), forKey: "mostRecentPushNotification")
}
```

Comment: How is this detecting if you received a push notification and did not launch from it?

Comment: I am interested in detecting when a notification was received and the user launched the app directly from the spring board after that and not from the notification alert itself

Comment: I tried and unfortuantely doesn't work , as the method doesn't get called unless the app is working in background

Comment: @M_Waly you don't have your push notification setup correctly then. You have to have the ` content-available` flag set in it. See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390868/apple-push-notification-in-background-issue/19403462#19403462

Comment: Changing `content -available` changes how notifications are delivered, so not always suitable. IMO this answer doesn't answer original question: 1 - the app is not launched at all (not on background); 2 - notification is received (could be notification with top priority, so cannot have `content -available` set to 1 as suggested); 3 - user launches the app from icon, not notification --> how to detect outstanding notifications?

Answer (score 2):

From documentation of 
`- application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`

> the system calls this method when your app is running in the foreground or background.

But, as you may have found out by your question

> However, the system does not automatically launch your app if the user has force-quit it. In that situation, the user must relaunch your app or restart the device before the system attempts to launch your app automatically again.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // ...
    if (launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]) {
        [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]];
    }
}
```

This should work.

The moment you open the app, the notifications you have received in notification center that you will get as a payload in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and then you can perform the specific operation.

Comment: only if the app was in background or foreground or launched from a  notification alert , what about the case when it is neither in background or foreground but received a push notification ,then launched normally from spring board?